# What does RiBasis which is described in RenderMan mean?

Tags: curve, 3dsmax, nurbs, renderman

I'm working on a plugin of 3ds Max. In this plugin, I export the geometry information into a .rib file which can be rendered by a RenderMan renderer. When I export a nubrs curve's data into .rib file described by RiBasis and RiCurve. I use the RtBsplineBasis in RiBasis, but I get the wrong result that the rendered curve is short than the result of 3ds Max's renderer. Then I reprint the first and the last control vertex, the curve is long enough, but its shape is a little different.Who can tell me how I get wrong result or what does RiBasis mean? How can get correct RiBasis? Thank u very much!

Answer (score 1):

RiCurve draws a cubic spline.  The control points do not uniquely determine the curve; you also need the *basis*, which is expressed as a 4x4 matrix -- one matrix give the coefficients you need for a B-spline, Bezier, Catmull-Rom, and so on, and of course you can also supply the matrix yourself for some kind of hybrid interpolant that isn't quite one of the standard 3 or 4.  The basis determines the character of the spline -- whether the curve is guaranteed to go through the control points or is merely approximating, the degree of continuity, the "tension", and so on.

There is a great discussion in one of the appendices of "The RenderMan Companion," including numeric examples of how different basis matrices affect the interpolation.

It sounds like you requested a B-spline basis, which is approximating (not interpolating) and continuous in both 1st and 2nd derivatives. Maybe that's not what you had in mind. It's hard to tell, since you didn't describe the properties of the spline that you were hoping for.

As an aside, approximating an arbitrary NURBS curve with a nonrational cubic is not always going to give you an exact match. Something else to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks very much，and I'm very sorry to reply so late. Now I've solved the problem and you helped me a lot.Please allow me to thank you again.